# Temporary table in Microsoft SQL Server dropped too early

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

We have a specific use-case originally implemented in Oracle, using Oracle's Global Temporary Table. Basically an application has to load specific items from the DB, based on application settings. This load takes a few minutes due to query execution times, and application logic building its internal structure (C++ app). There are multiple instances of this application, and they may want to load different set of objects from the DB at the same time.

In Oracle we solved this by introducing a Global Temporary table, which contains the IDs of the main objects to be loaded, and is filled by a stored procedure called by the application. If two instances call this SP at the same time, they will not affect each other, as the Global Temporary Table stores values on the session level. When the SP is finished, the application will use this Global Temporary Table in SQL joins to load the rest of the data.

We are trying to implement the same approach in MS SQL Server. As there are no Global temp tables here similar to Oracle, the SP is the one which creates a temporary table at the beginning:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_helper
(
    id DECIMAL NOT NULL
);
```

And then proceeds to fill it with data. When the procedure is finished, it selects the contents of the temp table as its output, and we can see that there are correct IDs in there. However, after that the table is gone, and throws "invalid object" error when using it.

As far as I know, the temp table should be kept until the connection which created it is closed. Based on the documentation:

"Local temporary tables have a single number sign (#) as the first character of their names; they are visible only to the current connection for the user, and they are deleted when the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server."

But even in the same connection, it is not available later. We tried the below sample Java program:

```
public class MSSQLDBTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x;database=XXX";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "XXX", "XXX"); PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_to_initiate(?)}")) {
            stmt.setInt(1, 1);
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                }
            }

            try (Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM #temp_helper")) {
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs2.getInt(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
40001
10001
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name '#temp_helper'.
```

But it is technically the same connection, so the table should be kept. Or do I misunderstand something? Table has to be a local temp table (single #), otherwise contents would be shared among sessions, which is exactly what we want to avoid. Otherwise we could use a normal table, and more columns to it and separate content belonging to specific application instance that way.

Comment: ["A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by the process that called the stored procedure that created the table."](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) And global temp tables (plural) are a thing -- they use `##` rather than `#`. Process-keyed tables admit much the same implementation.

Comment: Global temp tables are available. Even in Oracle though, you should probably use proper staging tables of temp tables, probably stored in a different location, using sizing, compression, indexing settings appropriate for their job

Comment: @JeroenMostert A-ha. Thanks, I missed this statement. I think I can understand this "limitation" though, based on how temp tables are handled in MSSQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This table is not used very frequently, only when app is loading its data, which happens maybe 1-2 times a week as a planned operation, when business objects are changed, and then it's all served from memory. It only holds around 1100 - 1400 records, and only NUMBERs, nothing fancy.

Comment: It's not much of a limitation -- you are free to create the temp table outside the stored procedure first, then call the stored procedure, which may proceed to assume the table exists and fill it, then use it afterwards. Of course, if it doesn't exist (or has the wrong structure) you get a big fat error, but SQL Server "helpfully" defers compilation of the procedure contents otherwise to make this work.

Comment: @GáborMajor that's what staging tables are for, and they *do* need optimization. All the more reason if it's just 1400 records, you can allocate the data pages just once and be done with them. Temp tables aren't stored in memory anyway, unless you use SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Of course, but we are trying to use the same codebase for Oracle and MSSQL DB servers. And Oracle was first, the codebase was evolving in last 10 years. So now with MSSQL we are always looking for ways to implement or workaround something in the DB to make it work as it is in Oracle, instead of  looking for a common solution which works in both cases.

Comment: Be wary of this -- "let's keep code looking the same" is a deceptively simple approach that can give terrible results if you're not careful. Oracle's `NUMBER` is not at all the same thing as T-SQL's `DECIMAL`, for example (which is shorthand for `DECIMAL(18, 0)`), neither in range nor precision. A few more surprises and incongruities like this and you may end up with code that merely looks correct based on textual resemblance, but doesn't work like the original at all. Don't be too afraid to refactor DB specific logic so you're free to actually change it based on the provider used.

Comment: I would be happy to refactor, but no money for it, as usual. But so far it is working correctly, we are not hitting any cases where e.g. number range or precision would be a problem, and anywhere it is used, it is specified explicitly (e.g. DECIMAL(22,2) for NUMBER(22,2)).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so just in case anyone finds this in search of answer: we ended up creating the temp table from the application separately as a statement, then run the mentioned SP, then run the rest of the queries which are using the temp table. This is only in case of SQL Server, in case of Oracle, the first statement does nothing (NULL;).

Comment: Global temporary tables are available in SQL server, their creation is a bit different than in Oracle.
Unlike a regular temporary table which is prefixed by 1 hash sign, the global table has two - ##MyTempTable

Comment: Sure, but a global temp table is shared amongst active sessions. So, everyone sees the same data basically. But what we need is that separate active sessions see separate set of data in same table. Which is exactly what the global temp table in oracle does.